# How to overwrite theme of Material App while doing Navigator.push to a new scaffold?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

I am new to flutter and have a question hoping someone can answer this. in my app I have defined my theme in main.dart file as

```
MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: QamaiThemeColor,
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: QamaiThemeColor,
        fontFamily: 'Raleway',
        hintColor: White,
        textSelectionColor: White,
        primaryTextTheme: Typography(platform: TargetPlatform.iOS).white,
        textTheme: Typography(platform: TargetPlatform.iOS).white,
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          color: BlackMaterial,
        ),
      ),
```

now this theme is for the first 3 pages of my app. after I log the user in I want to apply a new theme in my Scaffold without using a new MaterialApp widget and defining theme for that. is this possible? so far I am using a new MaterialApp but I have to pass context of old Material App to avoid navigator.pop killing my app with a black screen. is there a better alternative to do this?

This is my 2nd page theme

```
MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: White),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with a state management library like provider... be sure to put in in deps in pubspec like this:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  provider: ^3.0.0+1
```

Then check this code snippet (**which is runnable - you can copy paste it**). Pay attention to the theme attribute of MaterialApp and how i change the themes in the onPressed() functions of the buttons.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  return runApp(MyApp());
}

class ThemeService with ChangeNotifier {
  static final ThemeData themeA =
      ThemeData.light().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.black);
  static final ThemeData themeB =
      ThemeData.light().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white);

  ThemeData _currentTheme = themeA;

  get currentTheme => _currentTheme;

  switchToThemeA() {
    _currentTheme = themeA;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  switchToThemeB() {
    _currentTheme = themeB;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

/// This Widget is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (_) => ThemeService(),
        child: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          ThemeService themeService = Provider.of<ThemeService>(context);
          return MaterialApp(
            theme: themeService._currentTheme,
            title: _title,
            home: HomePage(),
          );
        }));
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ThemeService themeService = Provider.of<ThemeService>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "Text on Scaffold Body",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                themeService.switchToThemeA();
              },
              child: Text("Theme A"),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                themeService.switchToThemeB();
              },
              child: Text("Theme B"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

To me this is the most simple way. You can change the theme whereever you are in the application just by getting a reference to the ThemeService with **ThemeService themeService = Provider.of(context);**

Comment: Thankyou for the reply you are amazing, I will try this out and let you know

Comment: is there a way to call this theme function in the initial state of a screen?

Comment: handling changes would be easier for me that way